# Use of ConsumerEndpointSpec.transactional() in Spring Integration DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-transactions, spring-integration-dsl

I have a question about the behavior of `transactional()` in the following example:

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow myFlow(
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory,
            TransactionManager transactionManager
    ) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(MY_CHANNEL)
                .routeToRecipients(route -> route
                        .recipientFlow(flow -> flow
                                .handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(entityManagerFactory)
                                        .namedQuery(DELETE_EVERYTHING)))
                        .recipientFlow(flow -> flow
                                .handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(entityManagerFactory)))
                        .transactional(transactionManager))
                .get();
    }
```

The idea is that I'm first deleting the contents of a database table, and immediately after I'm filling that same table with new data. Will `.transactional()` in this example make sure that the first step (deletion) is only committed to the DB if the second step (inserting new data) is successful? What part of the documentation can I refer to for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read this documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/transactions.html#transactions.

You assumption is correct as long as both recipients are performed on the same thread and, therefore, sequentially.

The `TransactionInterceptor` is going to be applied for the `RecipientListRouter.handleMessage()`. And that's where that "auction" for  recipient happens.

Do you have any problem with that configuration since you have came to us with such a question?

Comment: No, we didn't observe any problems so far with this configuration.